# Meteor loading Firebase Admin on Server Side

Tags: firebase, react-native, meteor

I am working on a React Native /  Meteor combo, Where Meteor is my server. I need to set up a Firebase admin instance to send an API request for triggering push notifications for my React Native app.

I have installed the Firebase NPM SDK, when I go to import and/or require the firebase.admin object instance is empty or incomplete. Works fine if I load it into a normal node app setup.

I am assuming there is a latency with the import/require. I looked at some wrapper packages but they are outdated and unmaintained.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
console.log(admin)
```

Should print

```
    FirebaseNamespace {
  __esModule: true,
  credential: 
   { cert: [Function: cert],
     refreshToken: [Function: refreshToken],
     applicationDefault: [Function: applicationDefault] },
  SDK_VERSION: '6.2.0',
  Promise: [Function: Promise],
  INTERNAL: 
   FirebaseNamespaceInternals {
     firebase_: [Circular],
     serviceFactories: {},
     apps_: {},
     appHooks_: {} },
  default: [Circular] }
```

But instead prints

```
{ default: {}, [Symbol(__esModule)]: true }
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Seems fairly clear, import of Firebase package does not render full object with in Meteor server lifecycle. Doesn't get more complicated than that, Meteor is notorious for instantiation issues.

This isn't a Firebase or code issue, its a platform issue. Anyone more familiar with Meteor than I will probably be able to answer this question.

Comment: I have not found an answer to this yet, but as a work around I made a call to firebase functions.